# I want to change the price based on the checkboxs selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

price should change depending on the checkboxes selected. (i.e) 2 set of checkboxes are there they have 3 values each. depending on the values selected the rpice should change which would be in a readonly input

```
if (document.getElementById("sedan").checked = true && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked = true) { 
    $("#trip_cost").val("2000");   
} else if (document.getElementById("Premiumx").checked = true && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked = true){      
    $("#trip_cost").val("3000");   
} else if (document.getElementById("Force").checked = true && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked = true){      
    $("#trip_cost").val("3050");    
} else {
  $("#price").val("");
}
```

Comment: `=` is used to set a value. You need to use `==` or `===` for comparing values. I'm voting to close this as a typo. Also note that you don't even need any operators here, as the `checked` property is a boolean anyway

Comment: And for boolean values instead of `document.getElementById("Premiumx").checked == true` you can just write document.getElementById("Premiumx").checked`, it will be sufficent to check if it's `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that you are using **[assignement operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment)** instead of **[comparison operator `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality)** , so the first condition will be always `true`.

And for boolean values writing `if(document.getElementById("Premiumx").checked)`is enough you don't need to write `== true`.

This is how should be your code:

```
if (document.getElementById("sedan").checked && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked) { 
    $("#trip_cost").val("2000");   
} else if (document.getElementById("Premiumx").checked && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked){      
    $("#trip_cost").val("3000");   
} else if (document.getElementById("Force").checked && document.getElementById("chtiru").checked){      
    $("#trip_cost").val("3050");    
} else {
  $("#price").val("");
}
```